# AppWarp Client initialisation is not working

Tags: c++, initialization, cocos2d-x, appwarp

I am trying to initialise AppWarp as follows:

```
AppWarp::Client::initialize(APPWARP_APP_KEY, APPWARP_SECRET_KEY);
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the following error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "AppWarp::Client::initialize(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >,
>   std::__1::basic_string,
>   std::__1::allocator >, std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >)", referenced
>   from:
>         AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() in AppDelegate.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Can you provide more info? Is this on windows or mac, are you using Visual Studio or XCode and for which platform you are trying to compile?

Comment: I am using Xcode, Everything is going good except room join. only one user is joining a room. Maximum allowed user is 5 in the room. Once I disconnect the joined user, second user get connect.

Comment: Are you getting the error mentioned in the question or the issue mentioned in your comment or both? For the room joining issue, are you able to connect to the Appwarp server?

Comment: i can now connect to appwarp server, i am only getting room join issues.

Comment: Could you share the complete code snippet you are using to join a room and the error code you are getting on onJoinRoomDone callback method?

Comment: This issue has been resolved, now i am getting little bit delay on onChatReceived, It  doesn't always Synchronise with  all connected users, How can I solve this?

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question below so it can help other users. As for the second question, you need to create a new question.